# creating an input file and running an external program in python

Tags: python, file

All,

I wrote a small python program to create a file which is used as an input file to run an external program called srce3d. Here it is:

```
   fin = open('eff.pwr.template','r')  
   fout = open('eff.pwr','wr')  
   for line in fin:
      if 'li' in line:
        fout.write( line.replace('-2.000000E+00', `-15.0`) )
      else: 
        fout.write(line)
   fin.close
   fout.close    
   os.chmod('eff.pwr',0744)
# call srce3d
   os.system("srce3d -bat -pwr eff.pwr >& junk.out")
```

This does not work. The input file gets written properly but srce3d complains of an end of file during read. The os.system command works fine with a pre-existing file, without any need to open that file.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you are missing the function calls for close.

```
 fin.close() ## the round braces () were missing.
 fout.close()
```

A better way to do the same is using contexts.

```
    with open('eff.pwr.template','r') as fin, open('eff.pwr','wr') as fout:
       ## do all processing here
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually close the file – you have to *call* `file.close`. So,

```
fin.close
fout.close
```

should be

```
fin.close()
fout.close()
```